# In Skyrim is it possible to use the console to target the nearest hostile npc

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Just clicking on the nearest npc won't fit my needs unfortunately. I would like to be able to use it in a script that finds my closest enemy and tells me the distance to them. I am hoping to be able to target the GetPos command on both the player and the nearest npc, determine the difference and output the answer. If anyone knows how to do this or can point me in the right direction for a tutorial that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any console commands that give you your functionality that you are looking for.

Comment: Would there be a way that I could make a copy of the detect life spell and modify it to suit my needs? Maybe by changing the range at which it highlights npcs?

Comment: That's very interesting. I'm not familiar with how mods work, but it's possible. I think you may be able to detect npc's that are under the influence of detect life. I'm still not sure if you'd be able to detect the "closest npc under detect life" though. Good luck with your search.